# Apex Chart - How to target and style one specific grid line?

Tags: javascript, charts, grid, apexcharts, gridlines

Does anyone has clue how to target specific grid line and style like in the example?
I know how to dash line with:

```
grid: {
          strokeDashArray: 10,
        },
```

But how can I target grid line according to the tick value?
[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rW7v4.png)

Answer (score 1):

Only way you can do it is via css

```
.apexcharts-gridline:nth-child(2) {
  stroke-dasharray: 10;
}
```

Or use annotations instead https://apexcharts.com/docs/annotations/

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted it by using annotations property. Here is an example:

```
// Breakdown line 
        annotations: {
            position: 'front',
            yaxis: [
                {
                    y: 3000,
                    strokeDashArray: 5,
                    label: {
                        position: 'left',
                        borderColor: 'transparent',
                        textAnchor: 'middle',
                        offsetY: -10,
                        offsetX: 50,
                        style: {
                            color: '#D0D4D9',
                            background: "transparent",
                        },
                        text: ''
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
```